# Bound together cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

My problem is very simple. Suppose I have the following table:
[image]

and this one:

[image]

Is there an automatic way to obtain the following without using a sequence of nested IF?

[image]

Comment: Pivot tables may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's suppose your first table is in `Sheet1` and the second on `Sheet2`, then on cell **C2** of `Sheet1` you have to put this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

It will take the value on `A2` (1), look for a matching value in the range `Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4`, and if there is a match, insert the value on column `2` (cat). The `FALSE` indicates that it must be an exact match .

Comment: As you use ˙FALSE˙ for third argument, result will be correct regardless of sorting. Read `VLOOKUP()` help: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: @ Máté Juhász You're right. I've edited my answer to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

Copy your columns A:B to J:K, and enter this formula in Column I: `=VLOOKUP(J2,E:F,2)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use INDEX and MATCH.
Enter this formula in C2, and drag down.

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$4,MATCH($A2,$E$2:$E$4,0))
```

Explanation:

```
MATCH($A2,$E$2:$E$4,0)
```

Look up the range E2:E4 (values = 1, 2, 3), and find the cell that matches A2 (value = 1). This will return the value 1, since A2 matches the *1st* value in the range.

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$4,1)
```

In the range F2:F4 (values = cat, dog, and house), take the 1st value, i.e. cat.

Comment: This method allows for future proofing. Suppose a new column is added, the VLOOKUP() will break as the column reference is static.